# display all the 1year back from current data in the table in db2

Tags: sql, database, date, db2, db2-400

```
cid name dob(timstamp dtype)
101  x    11-02-2019
301  y    12-12-2019
901  z    21-07-2018
111  a    02-07-2020
```

this is my table. i want to extract records of last 1 year from current date. so my output should be

```
 cid name   dob
    101  x    11-02-2019
    301  y    12-12-2019
    111  a    02-07-2020
```

Comment: *last 1 year from current date* does not include `11-02-2019` (I assume 11 is the day and 2 is the month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `WHERE` clause set the condition that `dob` is greater than  the current date minus 1 year:

```
select *
from tablename
where dob >= current_date - 1 year
```

If you want all the rows of the current and the previous year:

```
select *
from tablename
where year(current_date) - year(dob) in (0, 1)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=cf4039e8445bbde4314203a51fdee719).

Comment: getting some sql-401 error on the 1st, 2nd solution doesn't give expected answer in data studio db2.

Comment: @pooja You can see in the demo that both queries are syntactically correct. The 2nd query returns exactly the rows of your expected result. So I guess you don't use the queries correctly.

Comment: ya the second one works now. the first its not supported by data studio db2.In the second query if i want to display record of last 3 years what change i need to do in the query? Can you pls help with your solution

Comment: Change the where clause: `where year(current_date) - year(dob) between 0 and 3`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch records by doing minus of current year.

```
select cid, from t1 where year(dob) = year(getdate())-1
```